# Using Burpsuite

Tags: passwords, ip, brute-force

So I'm new to Burpsuite and I am trying to use it to brute force a password. However there are a few questions that I have:
If the password has a specific layout (e.g. ****  -all numbers) how could I brute force the 10000 possibilities?
If the site refuses to load due to the ip being untrustworthy how can I get around this?

If there is not a specific input box for the password how could I get the website to recognize a password has been entered and get it checked ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are new in using burp suite you can read some blogs from Portswigger explaining how to use burp for brute force attack:

```
https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/1964020-using-burp-to-brute-force-a-login-page
```

this blog may contain some answer of your questions.
As I understand from your 1st question It about using many possibilities so it may be done by using a payload for example a wordlist that contain `100000 all-numbers passwords` so you can construct this wordlist from internet there are a lots just search in google. In the other hand you can use Intruder tool in Burpsuite and click on the payload type choose the bit flipper it may give you the ability to test many combination of the password by placing each time a bit from your password.
2nd question is that you mean that your IP is banned ? 

3rd question : you can see if your password checked from the response you get from the intruder.

Comment: It's better to paste interesting content inside the answer, external links may be dead in no time.